# how can i move Value from that function to the other variable on the that is available on out of the function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
$(window).load(function(){

    $("body").click(function(){

        var s = window.getSelection();
        s.modify('extend','backward','word');        
        var b = s.toString();

        s.modify('extend','forward','word');
        var a = s.toString();
        s.modify('move','forward','character');

        var z=b+a;

        z= z.trim();

        var jvalue = "Fox";            

    });        

}); 

var kvalue = jvalue;
alert(kvalue);
```

Comment: This question is unclear. If you want us to help you we need to understand what the problem is. If you want some help writing the question, have a look at the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't very clear and the code is really hard to read, but I'll do my best.
You can't access a local variable outside of the scope of the function it's declared in.  If you want to set a variable outside of your function, you can declare the variable before your function:

```
var a = "hi";
$(document).ready(function(){
    a = "bye";
});
```

Comment: <html>


<script type='text/javascript'>

$(window).load(function(){

    $("body").click(function(){
 
         var s = window.getSelection();
        s.modify('extend','backward','word');        
        var b = s.toString();

        s.modify('extend','forward','word');
        var a = s.toString();
        s.modify('move','forward','character');
  
  var z=b+a;

       z= z.trim();

var jvalue = "Fox";

  
 });
  

}); 

  var kvalue = jvalue;
  alert(kvalue);

</script>